# My custom style doesn't work

Tags: titlesec

It is my first experience with LaTeX. This may be some sort of dummy question. But anyway. I've spend a day with TeXLive on Fedora. And here is the problem. I have some file 1:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{vit} % it's my own vit.sty file 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{vmargin}
\setpapersize{A4}
\setmarginsrb{2cm}{1.5cm}{1cm}{1.5cm}{0pt}{0mm}{0pt}{13mm}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\sloppy

\begin{document}

\chapter{AutoSDK}

blabla

\end{document}
```

and a second file which is my "own" style `vit.sty`:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\RequirePackage[loadonly]{titlesec}
\RequirePackage{color}
\definecolor{vit_black100}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1}
\definecolor{vit_gray90}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.90} %can be used as background color
\definecolor{vit_gray70}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.70} %can be used as background color
\definecolor{vit_gray5}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.05} %can be used as background color
\definecolor{vit_snow}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0} %can be used as background color
\definecolor{vit_whiteshadow}{cmyk}{0.50, 0.0, 0.0, 0.33}
\definecolor{vit_whitecolor}{cmyk}{0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.10}
\definecolor{vit_yolkshadow}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.60, 1, 0.10}
\definecolor{vit_yolkcolor}{cmyk}{0.0, 0.10, 1, 0}

\titleformat{\chapter} 
    {\Large\slshape\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{vit_whiteshadow}} 
    {\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}%
    {1em}
    {\spacedlowsmallcaps}
    [{\color{vit_whitecolor}\titlerule[2.5pt]} 123]
```

and LaTeX returns the following error:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./AutoSDK.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, dumylang, nohyphenation, ge
rman-x-2012-05-30, ngerman-x-2012-05-30, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ibycus, arabi
c, armenian, basque, bulgarian, catalan, pinyin, coptic, croatian, czech, danis
h, dutch, ukenglish, usenglishmax, esperanto, estonian, ethiopic, farsi, finnis
h, french, friulan, galician, german, ngerman, swissgerman, monogreek, greek, h
ungarian, icelandic, assamese, bengali, gujarati, hindi, kannada, malayalam, ma
rathi, oriya, panjabi, tamil, telugu, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, 
kurmanji, latin, latvian, lithuanian, mongolian, mongolianlmc, bokmal, nynorsk,
 polish, portuguese, romanian, romansh, russian, sanskrit, serbian, serbianc, s
lovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, turkish, turkmen, ukrainian, uppersorbian, 
welsh, loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/book.cls
Document Class: book 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/bk10.clo)) (./vit.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/titlesec/titlesec.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/color.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvips.def)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/dvipsnam.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/utf8.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ot1enc.dfu)
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omsenc.dfu)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/vmargin/vmargin.sty
Package: vmargin 2004/07/15 V2.5 set document margins (VK)
) (/usr/local/texlive/2012/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/indentfirst.sty)
(./AutoSDK.aux)
! Undefined control sequence.
\reserved@c ...abelfalse \fi \ifnum \ttll@chapter 
                                                  >\c@secnumdepth \ttl@label...
l.13 \chapter{
              AutoSDK}
?
```

Comment: Why do you have the `[loadonly]` option to `titlesec`? If you remove that it compiles.

Comment: I'd suggest you make your Minimal Working Example more minimal; Try removing some of the other packages you have, until only your package is left. Also remove things such as sloppy: Basically, you want the minimum amount of code possible, so we can tell that the problem is what you think it is, and no somewhere else in the code.

Comment: I suggest you *not* to use `vmargin`, but `geometry` for setting the page parameters; for instance, `vmargin` is not compatible with `pdfpages` and other packages.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Remove the `loadonly` option for `titlesec`; i.e., instead of

```
\RequirePackage[loadonly]{titlesec}
```

use

```
\RequirePackage{titlesec}
```

in `vit.sty`. If you use the `loadonly` option, you will have to define the sectional unit formatting from scratch, and according to your definition for `\titleformat{\chapter}` you are not willing to do that.

You also need to make the following modifications to `\titleformat{\chapter}`:

```
\RequirePackage{textcase}
\titleformat{\chapter} 
    {\Large\slshape\bfseries\sffamily\color{vit_whiteshadow}} 
    {\textsc{\MakeTextLowercase{\thesection}}}%
    {1em}
    {}
    [{\color{vit_whitecolor}\titlerule[2.5pt]}123]
```

- You were using `\textcolor{vit_whiteshadow}` but `\textcolor`
  requires two arguments, so I changed it to `\color{vit_whiteshadow}`.
- Since you are using `\MakeTextLowercase`, you need the `textcase`
  package; by the way, do you really need `\MakeTextLowecase` for
  `\thesection`?
- You are using `\spacedlowsmallcaps` which is not a standard LaTeX
  command, so you also need to load the package providing this command if you want to use it;  however, the only package I know that provides this command is `classicthesis` and loading this package will totally change your layout which might not be what you want; if you want to use this command on its own, you could copy the definition of `\spacedlowsmallcaps` from `classicthesis.sty`.

Comment: thank you! I seems works. But here is another problem: Package titlesec Error: Entered in horizontal mode.
If you'll send me to google I won't be offended :)

Comment: @dmigous I updated my answer with some explanatory comments.